# Can't print a string in reverse order in C

Tags: c

I have written this simple program to print a string in reverse order but it is showing segmentation fault.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
        char *string;
        int n;
        printf("Enter a string\n");
        scanf("%s",string);
        printf("\n");
        n = strlen(string);
        printf("%d",n);
        while(n != 0)
        {
                printf("%c",string[n]);
                n--;
        }
        return(0);
}
```

Can anybody explain me why I am getting this segmentation fault? Opearating system : Ubuntu , compilor : gcc

Comment: You'll also want to subtract 1 from `n` in your `while()` loop to avoid the infinite loop you currently have.

Comment: You're also not changing `n` in your `while()` loop... Add `n--` before the closing `}` of the `while`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char *string` creates a variable which *can* hold a pointer to a string, but it is not set here.  So it points to a random location which, when accessed, segfaults.

To be useful, either allocate some memory and assign that to the pointer:

```
char *string = malloc(1000);  // big enough for string
```

or, do it all at once:

```
char string[1000];
```

Ideally, instead of using a hardcoded constant (like my example `1000`) use a symbolic constant, or better yet, find out how long the string needs to be and then use that.

Comment: It's necessaro to specify this 1000 or whatever number?? Is there anyway to not to have this limit??

Comment: @narayanpatra: whether you declare it as an array or allocate it dynamically with `malloc`, you *will* have to specify the size of the buffer you want.  C will *not* automatically allocate or grow buffers as you add to them.

Comment: But you can of course keep growing the buffer as you read the string.  See my answer where I have an example of this.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your code, which I highlighted:

-you don't allocate memory for the string

-you try to access an array element which is out of bounds

-you forgot to decrement n, so you'll have an infinite loop

Remember that arrays in C are 0-based.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
        char *string = malloc(100); //forgot to allocate memory
        int n;
        printf("Enter a string\n");
        scanf("%s",string);
        printf("\n");
        n = strlen(string);
        printf("%d",n);
        while(n != 0)
        {
                n--; //forgot to decrement here, so infinite loop
                     //crash was also from here, string[n] is not a valid index
                printf("%c",string[n]);
        }
        return(0);
}
```

Comment: There is no *new* operator in C. Perhaps you meant to use malloc().

Comment: You used `operator new` and the question is tagged C, not C++.  You also didn't free the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

`%s` with `scanf` does not allocate anything.  The caller is supposed to allocate.  Even if you *were* allocating something, since you don't know how big the string in the input stream is going to be, this is akin to doing `gets`, which is bad for security and stability reasons.

One of the simplest things you can do is have a pre-set constant amount of characters and use fgets:

```
char string[256];

if (!fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin))
{
   // TODO: handle error
}
```

This puts an artificial limit to the maximum size of the string.  Another approach would be to use dynamic memory.  Here's just a quick example that grows the buffer as-needed.

```
char *buf = NULL;
size_t current_len = 0, current_alloc = 0;
int c = 0;
int should_continue = 1;

while (should_continue)
{
   // Read a character...
   c = fgetc(stdin);

   // If c is EOF or a newline, let's zero-terminate the buffer and terminate
   // the loop...
   if (c == EOF || c == '\n')
   {
      c = 0;
      should_continue = 0;
   }

   if (current_len + 1 > current_alloc)
   {
      // Need to grow the buffer.
      void *newbuf;
      size_t newsize;

      newsize = current_alloc ? current_alloc * 2 : 256;
      newbuf = realloc(buf, newsize);
      if (!newbuf) { /* TODO: handle error */ }

      current_alloc = newsize;
      buf = newbuf;
   }

   // We've ensured capacity, now add the character.
   buf[current_len++] = c;
}

// TODO: use buf as string...

// Now free since we're done
free(buf);
```

As for reversing a string, this is just an example of a typical "string manipulation, C-style" way of doing things:

```
// Reverse the string in-place...

void reverse(char *s)
{
   if (*s)
   {
      char *t = s + strlen(s) - 1;

      while (s < t)
      {
         char u = *s;
         *s++ = *t;
         *t-- = u;
      }
   }
}
```

With this, after reading you can do:

```
reverse(string);
puts(string);
```

Comment: This is something new for me. Thanks. Let me try this.

Comment: @narayanpatra - In practice you might use a library for this (for example GNU readline does this), or put the line-reading code in your own library...  And while it's not C, C++ style I/O handles more of this sort of thing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Like @wallyk already said:

```
char* string
```

is actually a pointer to a character. You must allocate memory for the string using either,

```
malloc or calloc
```

so you can do something like:

```
char* string;
string = (char*) malloc( 50 * sizeof(char) );
```

which will allocate 50 characters for string. If your string is more than 50 characters, simply allocate appropriately.

Another way to do this is instead of creating a pointer, you can (not dynamically) allocate memory as follows:

```
char string[50]
```

That will also allocate 50 characters to string.

Answer (score -1):

You have declared the string as `char *` and you didn't assign the address, so it points to the variable address.